# Identify files in one folder that aren't in another folder

Tags: macos, file

I'd like to compare two folder structures and identify the files that are in Folder1 but aren't in Folder2.  Note that Folder1 and Folder2 have different structures.

I got close with this diff command, but it only works if the folder structures are the same:

```
diff -rqp Folder1 Folder2
```